# Ansible, mounting nfs file system from Linux to AIX

Tags: nfs, ansible

I am trying to mount the file system from Linux to AIX using ansible and tried few ways, but still getting an error in the pipeline. I can manually mount the filesystem. 
I tried

```
- name: Mount share storage on AIX system
  shell: "/usr/sbin/mount  system1.surce:/src/data  /share"
```

But getting a permission error, I tied using `become: yes` also but no luck.
2. then I tried using mount module.

```
- name: Mount share storage on AIX system
  mount:
    path: /share
    src: system1.surce:/src/data
    fstype: nfs
    state: present
    fstab: /etc/filesystems
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Post all relevant details of the errors. (See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and take a look at [How do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as well.)

Comment: For the record: AIX is not listed among Ansible Galaxy platforms. Statement of the  [AIX Working Group](https://github.com/ansible/community/wiki/AIX) "AIX works out of the box with most of the standard Unix modules".